# Root password recovery, makes Ubuntu unsafe?

Tags: password, encryption

I am using Ubuntu as my main OS. I am not an expert at all, and found myself not able to login to my pc, since I forgot my password. But then I found out that it is super easy to reset the password. That is a big concern for me. I use google chrome to save all my passwords and have it to autologin to my google account. I thought that was safe as long I had enabled password login. Even if my computer got stolen, without my password, the bad guys will not be able to login to my pc.

So my question is. How do I make my computer safe again. Do I have to encrypt my pc since as far as I understand, resetting root password will not change the encryption password.

Comment: You can change the password on a non-encrypted, non-network-controlled-windows login just as equally (eg. most home consumer windows laptops and desktops), but enhanced security is an option (costs money for most windows options, but encryption is free with GNU/Linux)

Comment: "makes Ubuntu unsafe?" No. In this case the idea is: when you have PHYSICAL access to the machine you OWN it, Literally. The alternative is far far worse: forget your password with no way to reset it means you need to format the system. "Even if my computer got stolen, without my password, the bad guys will not be able to login to my pc." But you do not store sensitive data on a notebook. Ever. Use an encrypted usb,. I use my notebook for work and if I have any client data on my machine and I need to tell my boss I had it on it I am in trouble with my boss.

Comment: If you want real safety: encrypt the contents and make a start up service that destroy the content of the disk if someone does not follow a specific procedure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to encrypt your filesystem. Any operating system can very easily have its passwords reset if an attacker gains physical access, as they can just read/write the filesystems by attaching your storage devices to their own machines. Encrypting the filesystems prevents that. So if this bothers you please consider using full disk encryption which can be configured from the Ubuntu installer.