# ubuntu changes administrator user password from recovery menu

Tags: login, password

I want to know why ubuntu consent to change password (with passwd username) of any users from the recovery menu without any admin password request. Is there any way to set a password to avoid this?

I ask because a classmate changes my ubuntu password to show me it's unsafe ... is that so?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Root password recovery, makes Ubuntu unsafe?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1321526/root-password-recovery-makes-ubuntu-unsafe)

Comment: See also [How to secure my laptop so that hacking by physical access is not possible?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676545/how-to-secure-my-laptop-so-that-hacking-by-physical-access-is-not-possible)